# In perl, print the last item value from JSON data

Tags: json, perl

I have data as shown in below example in a `JSON->new` variable, I need to print only the last 'ref' which is `DEF`, the size may vary, is there an easy way than looping and printing the last item? thanks.

```
$VAR1 = {
      'patchSets' => [
                  {
                    'ref' => 'ABC',
                    'id' => '123'
                  },
                  {
                    'ref' => 'PQR',
                    'id' => '456'
                  },
                  {
                    'ref' => 'DEF',
                    'id' => '789'
                  }
                ]
    };
```

EDIT: well, the code snippet looks as shown below to print the first element which works good, but I need to print last element:

```
my $json = JSON->new;
my $json_text = `ssh -p $port $host gerrit query --format=JSON project:path/to/project --patch-sets $commitId`;

#truncate {"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":6}
$json_text = ( split /\n/, $json_text )[0];
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);
#print Dumper $data;
print $data->{patchSets}[0]{ref};
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+find+last+item+in+a+perl+array

Comment: You've dumped a Perl hash. What does the Perl code look like? At any rate, `$array[-1]` will give you the last element of an array. If you edit your post to include your actual code, I can provide you with a complete answer.

Comment: it works, please post it as answer. thanks a lot. how -1 is picking last element?

Comment: See my answer for a description of why -1 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `-1` as the subscript

To access the last element of the array (reference), you should use `-1` as the subscript:

```
print $data->{patchSets}[-1]{ref};  # DEF
```

From [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Subscripts):

> The array indices start with 0. A negative subscript retrieves its
>   value from the end.

#### Using `$#` as the subscript

Another way to get the last element that's arguably less clear in this case because of the nested references is to use `$#` to get the last index:

```
print $data->{patchSets}[$#{$data->{patchSets}}]{ref};  # DEF again
```

#### Using array size minus one as the subscript

You could achieve the same thing as `$#` by getting the size of the array and remembering to subtract 1 from it, but again, not very readable and kind of painful syntax to look at:

```
print $data->{patchSets}[scalar(@{$data->{patchSets}}) - 1]{ref};  # yep... DEF
```

#### Using `pop()`

Finally, there's a very readable alternative that comes with a caveat. You could `pop` to get the last array element, but that actually modifies the array, which might not always be what you want.

```
my $last = pop(@{$data->{patchSets}});
print $last->{ref};  # still DEF
```

This is what `$data` will look like when you're done:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'patchSets' => [
                           {
                             'ref' => 'ABC',
                             'id' => '123'
                           },
                           {
                             'ref' => 'PQR',
                             'id' => '456'
                           }
                         ]
        };
```

Comment: A downvote? Geez... tough crowd. Anonymous downvoter: it would be helpful to leave a comment explaining _why_ you downvoted this answer.

Comment: For my money, you have written a lazy answer that responds only to the subject line of a poor question. Stack Overflow isn't a forum but a *knowledge base*. So while it may be tempting to grab 25 experience points from someone who will accept and upvote your response, it isn't good for the site. And no, neither of your downvotes come from me

Comment: We're probably getting into meta territory here, but this answer: a) answered the question that was asked, b) provided context for why the answer works, and c) even provided a viable alternative solution. If you're saying that the question shouldn't have been asked in the first place, that's hardly the fault of the person answering it!

Comment: If you think that those are the qualities that make a good answer then you're beyond help

Comment: Those are the things that make a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) according to  _Stack Overflow_, not just to me!

Comment: Look, I didn't downvote you, I tried to explain why your answer is lacking IMO. If you can't understand now why it takes more than beef and tomatoes to make a good chilli then you're on your own

Comment: Your answer explains that perl handily offers [-1] addressing to obtain the last element of an array. You might also mention that you can address from the end to the beginning with more negative indices. And you could mention how perl provides the array size $#

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: Careful. `$#array` is not the array size, it's the last index into the array (so, basically, the same as `-1`). Because array indexes are zero-based, the size of the array is `$#array + 1`.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill I agree, thanks for the constructive feedback.